# How do I link the source of a framework in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have a framework in my project.

I recently got git access to code. Is there some way I can link the source to that framework so when I step through breakpoints it will show me code instead of assembly instructions?

I would like to do this without having to rebuild the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1) clone the project, and add the framework project to your project.

2) insure that the base project has 'DWARF with dSYM File' enabled when its build, the symbols NOT stripped from the binary, and the dSYM file saved within the included framework.

My guess is that the original author did not do the second option, so your option is the first one.